# Rails Nested Attributes, Relationship for Shared or Common Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-key-relationship, nested-attributes

This has to be a common problem, so I'm surprised that Google didn't turn up more answers.  I'm working on a rails app that has several different kinds of entities, those entities by need a relation to a different entity.  For example:

1. `Address`: a Model that stores the details of a street address (this is my shared entity)
2. `PersonContact`: a Model that includes things like home phone, cell phone and email address. This model needs to have an address associated with it
3. `DogContact`: Obviously, if you want to contact a dog, you have to go to where it lives.

So, `PersonContact` and `DogContact` should have foreign keys to `Address`.  Even, though they are really the "owning" object of `Address`.  This would be fine, except that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` is counting on the foreign key being in `Address` to work correctly.

What's the correct strategy to keep the foreign key in `Address`, but have `PersonContact` and `DogContact` be the owning objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should use a [**polymorphic association**](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association).

For that you'll need to add an `addressable_id` and an `addressable_type` on your `addresses` table. And your models should look like:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true    
end 

class PersonContact < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end

class DogContact < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_one :address, :as => :addressable
end
```